# How access valid property of subgroup from template of angular reactive form element

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to add an error class when a form element has an invalid value but I can not access it and I can not figure how to do it.

**code.component.ts**

```
this.dateRangeForm = this.fb.group({
      from: this.fb.group({
        fromYear: new FormControl(null, [ValidYearsValidator]),
        fromMonth: new FormControl(null, []),
        fromDay: new FormControl(null, [])
      }),
      to: this.fb.group({
        toYear: new FormControl(null, []),
        toMonth: new FormControl(null, []),
        toDay: new FormControl(null, [])
      })
    });
```

code.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="dateRangeForm">
    <span formGroupName="from">
      <input type="text" [ngxOnlyNumbers]="true" maxlength="4" class="date-form-input" formControlName="fromYear"
        size="4" [class.error]="!fromYear.valid">
```

My problem is in the last input of the code below. I am trying to access the fromYear.valid property but I get this error after loading the form:

**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined**

Comment: What is the value of `fromyear` ?

Comment: a number, I set the value after an api call and set if any, if not it starts with null value

Comment: The 'formYear' in `[class.error]='!fromyear.valid`, is a property of the component, not a `formControlName` or a control's value, verify that you have a variable named `fromYear` in your component.

Comment: yes... This was my last attempt, I cannot access to dateRangeForm.from.fromYear.valid

Comment: Ok, solved it... I had to access with:       <input type="text" [ngxOnlyNumbers]="true" maxlength="4" class="date-form-input" formControlName="fromYear"
        size="4" [class.error]="!dateRangeForm.controls.from.controls.fromYear.valid">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You the access the controls using  `dateGroupForm.controls.from.controls.fromYear`.

You can then access the properties of that control (value,status etc.) using `dateGroupForm.controls.from.controls.fromYear.value`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the status of a form control inside of a nested form group this is the way to access it:

```
  <input type="text" [ngxOnlyNumbers]="true" maxlength="4" class="date-form-input" formControlName="fromYear"
    size="4" [class.error]="!dateRangeForm.controls.from.controls.fromYear.valid">
```

**dateRangeForm.controls.from.controls.fromYear.valid**

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a `get` method in your component to access the `fromYear` property.

Example:

```
get fromYear(){
 return this.dateRangeForm.get('from.fromYear');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I solved this by accessing directly the form, I think i was coding to early in the morning hehehe